# How to spawn telnet session based on user input

Tags: bash, expect, telnet

I created a script that queried everything on a specified device, however too much data is printed and I'd like to be able to query specific areas of the device configuration depending what arguments are passed.

My initial script which prints everything works fine

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set hostName [lindex $argv 0]
set timeout 2
spawn telnet $hostName
expect -re "login"
send "xxx\n"
expect -re "Password:"
send "<password>"
sleep 0.5
send "<query 1>"
sleep 0.5
send "<query 2>"
interact
```

Now I am creating a help section which involves including bash, and am having some trouble getting both expect & bash to work at the same time, along with being able to interact at the end. Does anyone have any advice?

with the below, the help function works but the send commands etc. don't work

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
```

With the below I am unable to run the help menu

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#!/bin/bash
```

I get this error:

```
invalid command name "Help()"
while executing
"Help()"
(file "./xxx" line 5)
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Mixing 2 different languages into one program is a recipe for failure. A script can only be controlled by a single interpreter. Expect is an extension of the [tag:tcl] language, so you'll be able to implement the addition code with Tcl.

Comment: you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect)

Comment: You could build a bash script that asks the user what he wants to query, and then call an expect script with arguments.  Look at this for expect script arguments: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-pass-argument-in-expect-command-749457/